# Javascript "Invalid Date" error in Safari

Tags: javascript, regex, date, safari

I've been trying to debug a script of mine and I can't get my head around what's wrong with this:

```
var date = new Date("19871104071535".replace(
    /^(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)$/,
    '$4:$5:$6 $2/$3/$1'
));
alert(date);
```

It works in Firefox, IE, Chrome but Safari gives me an "Invalid Date" error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Time` and `Date` are in the wrong order (for just Safari I guess :):

I tested this in Safari and it works (I just swapped Date and Time position in the final string):

```
var date = new Date("19871104071535".replace(
    /^(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)$/,
    '$2/$3/$1 $4:$5:$6'
));
alert(date);
```

It will also work in the other browsers because this is what is expected.